# How should I level a 2nd layer of subfloor?

Tags: subfloor, leveling

So I am adding a 2nd layer of subfloor of 5/8.
I have a bunch of dips and valleys on the current subfloor. Should I level it before installing my 2nd layer by using shims?

Or should I level it after I've installed the 2nd layer of 5/8 subfloor

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding an entire new layer of sheathing then you should level over the existing floor first. This allows you to use something like screed thinset or leveling compound, or roofing felt or many alternatives.

Once you have a more level substrate then you can glue and screw the new boards on. Use two large tubes of subfloor glue per 4x8 sheet, then use decking screws.

If all goes well you have a new layer of level plywood that's well laminated to the surface below. All the shims, glued, and other hacks needed to make it level are permanently entombed in glue and screws beneath your new wood.

Comment: agree but don't use anything that can crack in between the layers.  no SLC / no thinset.  If it cracks and the layers delaminate you can end up with a snap crackle pop floor assembly.  I'd use glue and wood ( door skin, 3/8, 1/2 ply ).  PL400 or some subfloor adhesive that has elasticity to it can be troweled to get the edges feathered where you've patched.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger also, if something cracks, it can shift out of place, potentially causing *more* bumpiness in the 2nd layer of subfloor!

Comment: So perhaps layer sone 1/4 or 3/8 ply to shim it to the level height and then glue it and screw it all down to achieve the level floor?

Comment: Leveling compounds are used all the time. If you then use sufficient glue and screws to sandwich them they're not going anywhere even if they crack. The key is to use enough adhesive.